# Are you allowed to shuffle your library at any time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Of course, there are some spell cards that allow you to look through your deck to find some sort of card, usually sorcery cards that let you find basic lands in your library or something and then shuffle it.

Anyway, what if I am in a situation where I seem to only be drawing cards that are too expensive in mana cost or I'm only pulling lands? Am I allowed to shuffle my library at any time, or do I have to deal with what I get or cast some kind of sorcery or instant that lets me find a card/cards then shuffle my library?

Comment: Even if you could, it wouldn't help. Assuming that you shuffled properly when instructed to (at the beginning of the game, or when a card said so), the pattern of cards you have previously drawn has no predictive power regarding the next card you draw. In other words, if you are "only pulling lands", you are no more likely to draw another land if you don't re-shuffle than if you do. And if you didn't shuffle properly before, there's no reason to assume that you will do so now.

Comment: @murgatroid99 True, except for the last sentence: "And if you didn't shuffle properly before, there's no reason to assume that you will do so now." People make mistakes. Assume for a moment you realize a turn after shuffling you made a mistake somewhere in the process. That would make this a legitimate question.

Comment: Do you have an actual concrete example? You don't *accidentally* stack your deck. You don't *accidentally* pile shuffle. You don't *accidentally* look at the cards and then *accidentally* fail to reshuffle. Shuffling isn't some complex process that you can invalidate by missing a step half-way through. You just riffle a few times.

Comment: @JoeWallis That's a very different question, one where the answer is basically "call a judge" or in casual play "pretend to be a judge." Keep in mind that if that does happen, you still broke the rules - it's just that it was an accident. If you do end up (re)shuffling your library, it's not because you're allowed to whenever you want, it's because it's the least bad way to remedy a mistake.

Comment: @JoeWallis My point is that that is not actually "legitimate". It's still breaking the rules. However you end up dealing with it, it's separate from this question, and separate from murgatroid's point about re-shuffling not helping the OP's problem (cards too expensive, too many lands).

Comment: I feel like Murgatroid's comment should be a part of an answer to this. Sure the question in the title as-asked can be answered with a simple "no" and a rules quote, but the question makes it clear that the asker is misunderstanding something fundamental about the way shuffling and randomization works if he thinks that reshuffling would address the issue he's having.

Comment: @GendoIkari I took your advice and expanded that comment into an answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't shuffle whenever you want; rule 401.2 explicitly handles this case.

> 401.2. Each library must be kept in a single face-down pile. Players can’t look at or change the order of cards in a library.

Plus, if you could shuffle at will, it would make cards that let you shuffle like [Ponder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=244313) pretty redundant.

Comment: The real redundant card here is Myr Mindservant.

Comment: It would also make almost any card with "Play with top card of your library revealed" insanely overpowered.

Comment: Ponder wouldn't actually be redundant in this case.

Comment: And everyone would be playing [Psychogenic Probe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46582) :) not really a fun alternative reality ...

Comment: @Autar: But the free shuffles wouldn't be caused by a spell or ability, and even if they counted, you'd need to make the *opponent* shuffle.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh you're right, doesn't work ... Well, one less crappy alternative reality to worry about :)

Answer (score 4):

**Absolutely not.**

As a general rule of thumb, unless the rules say you CAN do something at a specific time, you **can't**.

You can only shuffle your deck before you've started your game or when a specific card tells you you can.  As a side note - if it doesn't say "**may**" when it talks about shuffling your deck, it's mandatory.

The exact rule was already added, so I'll just comment a bit more explanation:

There are far too many scenarios where the ability to shuffle your deck at any time would be game-breaking.  It would also take various 'punishments' of cards meaningless (ex: "Send a card to the bottom of your opponent's library").

Answer (score 3):

You cannot shuffle whenever you want. As other answers have already pointed out, rule 401.2 says that you are not allowed to reorder your library.

I'll need this definition later, so I'll quote it now. The rule defining shuffling is [701.16a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Shuffle):

> To shuffle a library or a face-down pile of cards, randomize the cards within it so that no player knows their order.

Even if you could shuffle whenever you want, it generally wouldn't actually help. To be specific, say you have 40 cards left in your library, and you just shuffled (perhaps because you just activated [Evolving Wilds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Evolving%20Wilds)). Now, you know *what* cards are in your library, but *by definition* you don't know what order they're in. Then you draw a Forest, which you didn't want because you already have enough land. Now you still know what cards are in your library, because you can just subtract one Forest from the cards you knew were in there before. And you *still* don't know what order the cards are in. You know there *was* a Forest on top, but that doesn't help, because that Forest isn't in your library anymore.

Now imagine that you could shuffle your library right now. Obviously, the library now has the same cards as before. And again, by the definition of shuffling, you don't know what order the cards are in. And you should be able to see that this hasn't actually changed anything: both before and after shuffling, you know what cards are in the library, and both before and after shuffling, you don't know what order they're in.

Now, you might ask "But, if it doesn't change anything, why *can't* I shuffle whenever I want?" The answer is that I was describing the general case, and there are some cases where it does matter because you *do* know where some of the cards are. And then the ability to choose to shuffle would give you and advantage. [Jace, the Mind Sculptor]'s first ability would be completely useless if you could shuffle; your opponent could say "I leave that card on top" and then you could just say "Actually I'll just shuffle it away". [Brainstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brainstorm) would be much better if you could just draw 3 cards and then shuffle your 2 worst cards back into your library, instead of being forced to draw them back for the next two turns. [Garruk's Horde](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370684) would be crazy powerful: you could just shuffle until you see the creature you want, and then cast it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot shuffle your library at any time. Your opponent can force you to put "bad" cards on top of your library using spells such as [Roil Spout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Roil%20Spout), so it is strategically relevant.